# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{n\log n}{e^n}$ converge absolutely?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check whether the series converges absolutely:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{n\log n}{e^n}$$

I tried tests like Ratio, Raabe but not working

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).

Comment: This is the derivative of the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Answer (score 2):

The ratio test should work just fine. If $a_n = (-1)^n \frac{n \log n}{e^n}$ then $$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| = \frac{n+1}{n} \frac{\log(n+1)}{\log n} \frac 1e$$ which converges to $\dfrac 1e$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: why is $\frac{log(n+1)}{log n}$ =1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: One explanation is that $\log(n+1) - \log n = \log(1+1/n) \to 1$, so that $\log(n+1)/\log n - 1 \to 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n=(-1)^n\dfrac{n\log n}{e^n}\implies\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{\left \lvert a_n\right \rvert}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[\large n]{\dfrac{n\log n}{e^n}}=\dfrac{1}{e}\left(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n\log n}}\right)=\dfrac{1}{e}<1$

Comment: To the downvoter, is there anything wrong in my argument?

Comment: Nothing's wrong: some simply can't understand basic mathematics and/or are bored and just downvote. Your answer is fine. +1